# Acomodar imagen

Tags: html

```html
    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top white-bg" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">

              <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">

            <div class="row border-bottom" style="margin-bottom: 0; background: #ffffff; padding: 0px;">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0; height:25px; background: transparent;">
              <div class="dropdown profile-element">
                <img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="http://localhost/Warehouse/assets/img/profiles/john.jpg" />
               </div>

              <li>
                 <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                 <span class="clear"> <span class="block m-t-xs"> <strong class="font-bold">David Williams</strong>
                  </span> <span class="text-muted text-xs block">Art Director <b class="caret"></b></span> </span> </a>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeInRight m-t-xs">
                     <li><a href="login.html">Logout</a></li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
            </nav>

            </ul>
          </nav>
```

Asi es como se mira:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que se mirara en una sola fila es decir, la foto de perfil y luego el nombre, al dar clic sale la opcion de `logout`, no se como acomodarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes agregar `display: inline-block;` a los elementos que desees que esten en linea.  Algo asi:

```css
img {  
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.profile-element, li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top white-bg" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">

              <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">

            <div class="row border-bottom" style="margin-bottom: 0; background: #ffffff; padding: 0px;">
              <!-- <img src="http://localhost/Warehouse/assets/img/Esterline.png"></img> -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0; height:25px; background: transparent;">
              <div class="dropdown profile-element">
                <img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" />
               </div>

              <li>
                 <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                 <span class="clear"> <span class="block m-t-xs"> <strong class="font-bold">David Williams</strong>
                  </span> <span class="text-muted text-xs block">Art Director <b class="caret"></b></span> </span> </a>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeInRight m-t-xs">
                     <li><a href="login.html">Logout</a></li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
            </nav>

            </ul>
          </nav>
```